# Arduino - struct out of scope why?

Tags: c, arduino

I work at a motor programm (and i have to control multiple motors thats why i use the struct) together with my arduino MEGA.
I dont't understand why MOTOR is out of scope when I use it as argument in the drive function:

```
typedef struct motor
{
   int EN;
   /*some more ints*/
}MOTOR;

MOTOR mot1;
MOTOR mot2; /*this works with no compile error*/
int drive (MOTOR*) /*here i have compile error out of scope, neither with or without pointer*/
{
   return 1;
}

void setup()
{}

void loop()
{}


sketch_jul25a:2: error: 'MOTOR' was not declared in this scope
sketch_jul25a:2: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
sketch_jul25a.ino: In function 'int drive(MOTOR*)':
sketch_jul25a:9: error: 'int drive(MOTOR*)' redeclared as different kind of symbol
sketch_jul25a:2: error: previous declaration of 'int drive'
'MOTOR' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Please include the exact error message from your compiler in your post verbatim.

Comment: @Clemens The statement numbers of the error messages do not correspond to the code you showed. So show the actual code.

Comment: @Clemens It seems that the problem is related ro header includings. Maybe you have a cicular header inclusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the road to hell is paved with good intentions.

The Arduino IDE tries to be helpful by generating prototypes for all user-defined functions at the beginning of the code. When one of these prototypes references a user-defined type, things blow up in the manner described.

The trick is to make the code unparseable by the IDE:

```
namespace
{
  int drive (MOTOR*)
  {
     return 1;
  }
}
```

The IDE runs into `namespace` and has no idea what to do with the block that follows, so skips it.

Comment: Well that's slightly brutal, as someone who only uses AVR-GCC I wasn't aware of this.

Answer (score 2):

And i suggest this should do the job as good as the namespace option?

```
struct motor
{
   int EN;
   /*some more ints*/
};
int drive (motor* mtr);
motor mot1;
motor mot2; /*this works with no compile error*/

  int drive (motor* mtr)
  {
   return 1;
  }


void setup()
{}

void loop()
{
  int a = drive(&mot1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: My original answer made some assumptions that Arduino IDE was closer to AVR-GCC than it actually was. My general recommendation for anyone who is familiar with C or C++ that is doing a lot of work with these chips is to use Atmel studio and AVR-GCC directly as you will run into less issues this way.

Arduino is actually C++ underneath but it does some preprocessing before it turns your code into the C++ code that gets compiled for the chip (like creating `main` from `setup` and `loop`). The issue you have is due to a preprocessing step and is explained by [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31630990/296460).

As a more general c++ usage note I'd recommend changing your struct definition to this:

```
struct motor
{
   int EN;
   /*some more ints*/
};
```

You might want to read [Difference between 'struct' and 'typedef struct' in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c) to see why things are a bit different in c++.

Comment: In C++ there is no need to specify the parameter name in the function definition.

Comment: will try this... same errors.
May i should make a class for it?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow you are correct. In this particular case I'm just taking a guess about the actual usage here as I can't see why a function that needs to do something based on a motor as a parameter can make any sense without actually passing in that parameter. If there's something I'm missing here I'd love to know.