# In C++ or Arduino, how do you accept an argument of unknown type in a function?

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

I'm trying to implement a `puts` method that simply logs stuff using Serial.print

```
void puts(char explanation, void value){
  if (log){
    Serial.print(explanation);
    Serial.println(value); 
  }
}
```

calling it like

`puts('hello', 12);` or `puts('hello', 'foo');`

currently I'm getting the error `'value' has incomplete type`

if I use `void* value` in the declaration I get the error `invalid conversion from 'int' to 'void'`

Comment: Probably try `void* value` as the type.

Comment: @Jashaszun I tried that and i get a different error, see my edit, thanks!

Comment: What does `Serial.println()` and `Serial.print()` expect? I'm guessing a `char *`?

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves you can pass `Serial.print()` any datatype

Comment: If you look at the source code for class Serial (actually its stream base class) there are several different print() methods, one for each of the supported data types. The C++ compiler still has to know the datatype at compile time, to call the correct method. So you might start by making a subclass based on Serial.

Comment: @MarkU So this is C++, not C? In that case, the question needs to be retagged.

Comment: Arduino language is basically C++, yes. [A little bit stripped down, maybe](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html#faq_cplusplus)

Comment: Um I'm just going to throw it out there.  You can use a template.  That is if it is c++

Comment: Interesting, thought it was closer to C than C++, but I dont really know, feel free to retag it.

Comment: No matter how you slice it, somewhere there has to be code to convert every type that this function is going to support into one or more characters that can be sent over the serial port.

Comment: Just FYI, the relevant println() source code (on Windows / Arduino IDE) is under Program Files / Arduino / hardware / arduino / avr / cores / arduino / Print.cpp and Print.h -- and yes, this is C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't actually use "unknown" types in C/C++; you can use *arbitrary* types, but *someone* has to know how to deal with it properly.

Fortunately C++ offers a solution so long as someone does know how to deal with it: **templates**. We can define a function that takes an arbitrary type and the compiler will instantiate as many copies of the function as is required to handle all the types thrown at it (if possible):

```
namespace
{
  template<typename T>
  void puts(char *explanation, T value){
    if (log){
      Serial.print(explanation);
      Serial.println(value); 
    }
  }
}

void loop() {
  puts("hello", 12);
  puts("goodbye", "foo");
  delay(1000);
}
```

(We use `namespace` in the sample above because [LOL Arduino IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630888/arduino-struct-out-of-scope-why).)

The downside of course is that each function instantiation takes up additional flash, which is why you probably don't want to use more than 3 or 4 if you can help it.